# Zend: ViewScript Decorator Does not Render Form Elements

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper, view-helpers

I am working with zend just recently. I discovered this ViewScript decorator for form and I find it a best alternative of using the
classic Zend Form Decorators. But I have problem on displaying the form. I got the code working but no display I get from the view.

Here are my codes:

**Form:**

```
class Application_Form_Registration extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {   
        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("username");
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit("submit");
        $this->setAction("/test.php");
        $this->setMethod("get");
        $this->addElements(array($username, $submit));
        $this->setElementDecorators(array(
          array('ViewScript', array(
            'viewScript'=>'test.phtml'
          ))
        ));
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Registration();
        $this->view->form = $form;

    }
}
```

**test.phtml (My ViewScript)**

```
<form action="<?php $this->escape($this->form->getAction()); ?>">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue;">
    <?php echo $this->element->username; ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->submit; ?>
</div>
</form>
```

**And my view (index.phtml)**

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

Did I missed something and / or made wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
  $this->setElementDecorators(array(
              array('ViewScript', array(
                'viewScript'=>'test.phtml'
              ))
            ));
```

with

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
              array('ViewScript', array(
                'viewScript'=>'test.phtml'
              ))
            ));
```

You have bassically overrided default decorator 'ViewHelper' hence there is nothing to show .

Both form (html form tag) and form elements (input type text,radio etc) uses decorators to display themselves . By calling setElementDecorators on Zend_Form instance you are overriding form elements decorators not form decorators for that we need to use setDecorators instead .

Comment: thanks buddy.. the code works for me.. but what totally is the difference between the two?

Comment: ahhh.. i got it.. so when we use the setElementDecorators, we overrode everything that surrounds it.. now i got it.. thanks.. :D

Answer (score 1):

believe it or not you access getAction in the partial using element->getAction, and don't forget to echo it:

```
//test.php
<form action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->element->getAction()); ?>">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue;">
    <?php echo $this->element->username->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->submit->render(); ?>
</div>
</form>
```

and the view would be:

```
//index.phtml
<?php echo $this->form ?>
```

Comment: thanks rocky... I've done what you instructed but still no form rendered / displayed.. have any idea?

Comment: The default location for a viewscript partial would be `/view/scripts/test.php`. It would be the same for any module.

Comment: yes.. I understand it.. currently I am not working with module yet but looking ahead for it. hmmm.. I'm just testing it in the default location.

Comment: check the edit and see if it works. I added ->render() to the elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9554/discussion-between-rockyford-and-aldee-mativo)